# Rails Atom Feed problems in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've setuped a atom feed in development on CodeAnyWhere with this url : 
http://mydevsite.codeanyapp.com:3000/posts.atom ...and everything is ok

When i push it in production to heroku here :
http://myprodsite.heroku.com/posts.atom

...i've an error --> "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

I don't know where it comes :(((

Cheers!

Comment: Please check the logs and find the section with the error and please post it here so we can check. Without it we will not have a clue either.

Comment: Ok is there my issue --> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass):. In my atom feed i'm using this to get the picture of the post --> entry.link href:game.photos[0].image.url(:thumb), rel:"enclosure", type:"image/jpeg" ... The problem is that i'm using cloudinary in production so it generates a error. How i can i fix it ? cheers

Comment: It seems like you have a game without photo and your code does not expect that.

Comment: Okay thanks ! cheers

Answer (score 0):

There might be some exception on heroku

please check log by using command `heroku logs` from terminal. Resolved the issue and then again deploy it on heroku.